# Pytest plugin opening GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pytest

I am trying to create a py.test plugin to reproduce Pydev for Eclipse behaviour, that you can see on the image below:

[image: Pydev]

**Basically, the idea would be to open an empty window during the call to `pytest_sessionstart()`, to fill it (update list of tests and progress bar) with objects returned by `pytest_runtest_makereport()`, and to close it with `pytest_unconfigure()`.**

I tried to achieve this with Tkinter, by using the following code:

```
import Tkinter


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    print "Tests are starting"
    Tkinter.Tk().mainloop()
    print "The window was opened"  # This step is never reached
```

When running the tests, it prints the first sentence, opens the window but doesn't come back to py.test until we close the window.
If I remove the call to `mainloop()`, the window is opened but instantly destroyed.
I also tried to open the window in a separate thread by doing:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=Tkinter.Tk().mainloop())
```

but without success. Anyway, the threading option doesn't seem very good as Tkinter has to run in the main thread, which is not possible in the case of a py.test plugin.

**So, does any of you have an idea about how to solve this problem? The only requirement is to keep py.test.**

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: try wxPython, http://wiki.wxpython.org/MainLoopAsThread

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried this solution however the app is crashing as soon as started.
The author describes three methods and only the first (which run the GUI in main thread) works.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter.Tk().mainloop() is a while True loop. You won't be getting out of it. There are two ways to solve your problem in my opinion:

1. Use pytest inside Tkinter app. You can invoke pytest within the tkinter code like [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code).
2. Use pytest in different thread and pipe the output of pytest to Tkinter app.